# A different pattern with a list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm facing a peculiar problem, recently I've felt the need to produce list comprehensions of a certain type.

For example:

```
[ re.search('xyz', l).group(0) for l in my_list if re.search('xyz', l) ]
```

Now as the keen reader might have observed this list comprehension does regexp matching twice.

I would like to eliminate this 'extra' overhead somehow losing out on the elegance of list comprehensions. Has someone faced such a problem before? If so how did they go about solving it?

In general I have a function `f()` that I apply to a value/object `x` from the list, now I wish to have `f(x).b` in my list if and only if `f(x).a` statisfies some condition.

I know

```
empty_list = []
for l in my_list:
    match = re.search('xyz', l)
    if match:
        empty_list.append(match.group(0))
```

or more generally:

```
empty_list = []
for x in my_list:
    val = f(x)
    if val.a == condition:
        empty_list.append(val.b)
```

is a possible solution, but this seems to be too verbose, I'm sure there is a more 'pythonic' way of doing this.

Comment: "elegance of list comprehensions" -- I think you've applied excess weight here.  Once your expression becomes complex enough, it no longer "belongs" in a comprehension (else it will be incomprehensible!)

Comment: You could use a nested list comprehension: `[ x.group(0) for x in [re.search('xyz', l) for l in my_list] if x ]`

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, that is what I meant, sorry, that is infact what I meant. Edited/fixed.

Comment: @tobias_k I think inner list comprehension can be generator statement

Answer (score 5):

Use generator comprehensions:

```
# Your original list of data.
my_list = []

# This 'knows' how to produce a new list of elements where each 
# element satisfies some test, here represented as `predicate`.
# Looks like a list comprehension, but note the surrounding parens.
passing = (x for x in my_list if predicate(x))

# This knows how to apply some function `f` to each element in the list.
mapped = (f(x) for x in passing)

# Now use the know-how above to actually create your list.
# Note that because you're using chained generators, you are 
# only iterating over the original list once!
results = list(mapped)

# Or if you don't need all the intermediate values at once...
for el in mapped:
  do_something_with(el)
```

Answer (score 4):

As @tobias_k said in a comment, you could use a nested comprehension (here a generator):

```
>>> [m.group(0) 
     for m in (re.search('xyz', item) for item in ['abc', 'aaxyz', 'xyz'])
     if m is not None]
['xyz', 'xyz']
```

For testing whether or not there was a match, I always use `if m is not None` rather than `if m`.  A failed match is always `None` (and testing for identity is really fast), while testing a real match object for truth calls a method on the match object, which can have a significant impact on runtime for a large enough number of match objects.  This doesn't matter if you aren't in the 100's of MB to GBs range of input text scale problems, but it doesn't hurt for smaller scale problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can factor the regexp into an intermediate generator comprehension if you want to avoid computing it twice.

Let's start with your for-loop solution

```
for l in my_list:
  match = re.search('xyz', l)
  if match:
    empty_list.append(match.group(0))
```

We can turn that into a double loop by artificially putting the match inside a one-element list:

```
for l in my_list:
  for match in [re.search('xyz', l)]:
    if match:
      empty_list.append(match.group(0))
```

Since this is now just a stack of for loops and if statements, it is trivial to convert it into a nested list comprehension:

```
[ match.group(0) for match in [re.search('xyz', l) for l in my_list] if match ]
```

And in fact, you can make the inner list into a generator comprehension if you want to avoid generating an unnecessary list

```
[ match.group(0) for match in (re.search('xyz', l) for l in my_list) if match ]
```

---

This last part isn't related to your question, but I wanted to note that some languages allow you to bind names inside of a list comprehension, which would allow you to write the entire thing as a non-nested list comprehension. The following isn't valid Python code, but it *could* be

```
[ match.group(0) for l in my list, let match = re.search('xyz', l), if match ]
```

For example, in Haskell you could write

```
[ group 0 match | elem <- myList, let match = reSearch "xyz" elem, match ]
```

which is valid code (modulo the fact that I made up all the function names).

Comment: The second bit `let match = re.search('xyz', l)` is exactly the sort of syntax I was hoping for, thanks for the informative nugget.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, in this case, I would just do this:

```
matches = [i.group(0) for i in filter(None, (re.search('xyz', i) for i in my_list))]
```

(without the `list` if you just need to iterate through it).

The `filter` yields all the elements of the generator expression that have a Boolean value of `True` (in this case, those that are not `None`).

However, if you wanted to check explicitly for `None` with this approach, you would need to something like this:

```
matches = [i.group(0) for i in filter(lambda x: x is not None, (re.search('xyz', i) for i in my_list)))]
```

Comment: *Map*. *Filter*. Why did I not think of using these? +1 for reminding me of these!